# Variable does not exist: fields [= getDescribe().fields]

Tags: unit-test, describesobject, platform-bug, test-automation, describesobjectresult

A couple weeks ago, in the nightly test runs some tests started failing randomly (I guess it is related to the Summer'17 release.)
I was not able to reproduce this, in console or Setup test runs they won't fail.
[This](https://github.com/mbotos/Automated-Testing-for-Force.com/blob/master/src/classes/TestRunner.cls) it the test-runner we are using.

Sometimes no tests fail, sometimes it's 30 or something in between. What they have in common is they have the same Error Message:

> Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation: Class
>   AnyClass: Variable does not exist: fields

The classes are different, but they are all doing something like this:

```
sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
```

The classes are either from the same package or another package, doesn't matter.

Anyone else experienced this? Any hint? any configuration?
Is "fields" kind of deprecated?

### **EDIT**

Today also the tests in the developer console failed due to this error. After rerunning, they completed.
BTW 2 of three packaging Orgs are affected by this.

Comment: We just started randomly receiving this error as well.  Did you find a solution?  It is happening in our production org that is still on Summer '17.  But just started last week.

Comment: @JRiffe thanks for letting me know. I informed SF that others are experiencing this too.

Comment: @JRiffe are you still experiencing this? the last 30 days no tests failed in our orgs.

Comment: I would have said no yesterday.  But seems it happened again last night where we received an exception email about it.

Answer (score 2):

This is the answer I finally got from Support, seems like the new compiler fixed it [maybe ;)]. At least I'm not receiving this error anymore for the last month.

> Hi Sebastian,
>
> Thanks for your patience.
>
> Since we have started the progress of upgrading the old compiler to
>   the new one, it may have caused this intermittent issue to Apex tests.
>   You will no longer have this issue.

Comment: Just ran into this with a subscriber org calling out managed package. It was falling over on a use of `fields` in the package. Will have the subscriber try recompiling all the Apex classes.

Comment: @DanielBallinger I will leave this unanswered since others are still experiencing this. Please keep us posted on your findings. thanks :)